# Работа с динамически добавленными элементами в jQuery (delegation, rebinding)

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

jQuery работает с элементами, которые были на странице на момент инициализации кода. Если добавляются новые элементы - при помощи ajax'а или функций типа append() - то события не затрагивают их.

Работать с динамически добавленными элементами, как я понял, можно при помощи делегирования (delegation) и пересвязывания (rebinding). *За перевод терминов не ручаюсь - буду рад уточнениям.*

Хочется понять суть этих двух процессов. Описания, с которыми я пока столкнулся, пока что не пролили свет на происходящее.

Comment: т.е. вас интересует **не как это сделать**, а **как это работает**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если кратко, то смысл делегирования в том, что обработчики "навешиваются" не на отсутствующие в dom элементы, а на существующий родительский объект, глобальный (документ, body и т.д.), но не обязательно, это может быть любой элемент, просто надо учитывать, что если этот элемент будет удален из dom (или перезаписан), то обработчики объявленные для его детей, в том числе не рожденных, отвалятся.

При объявлении указывается селектор объектов, к которым этот обработчик должен относиться. Таким образом, при срабатывании соответствующего события (у документа, body и т.д.), будет вызван данный обработчик для всех элементов, соответствующих селектору, даже если этих элементов не было во время объявлении обработчика (например при загрузке страницы).

Если нужно, то в документации более подробно описан механизм возникновения события как оно "доходит"(propogate) до document'а или до body, об event'е который передается в обработчик и других нюансах...

Comment: Так, это о делегировании. Тут, как я понял, принцип такой:

    $('#parent').click(function(event){
      var $tgt = event.target;
      if ($tgt == '.goal') {
        // do something
      }
    });

А пересвязывание? Там, как я понял, создается функция, в которую выносится добавление объекта на страницу. При этом сама функция вызывается не только в теле jQuery-скрипта, но и в самой себе. Более четкого понимания пока не сложилось.

Comment: В статье [jQuery.live в деталях](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64029/) очень подробно описывается работа метода live(), но сам принцип делегирования - по сути такой же как, как и в bind(), delegate(), on()

Comment: @Deonis, да. Я присмотрелся к этим методам - принцип и правда такой же. Хотелось бы понять также суть rebinding'а.

Comment: @Khvorostin можно пример rebinding'а? Не совсем понятно о чем речь в контексте динамического добавления объектов.

Comment: Да, конечно. [Вот здесь](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/05/working-with-events-part-2) описание с примерами есть.

Comment: Ну смысл в том, что добавление элемента осуществляется одновременно с заданием для него обработчика. Функция навешивает обработчик, который добавляет элемент. А чтоб навесить обработчик на этот новый объект функция вызывается снова внутри себя. Чтоб обработчики не накапливались делают для старых элементов unbind[All], потом bind уже для всех. 

Не совсем удачный пример, довольно редко когда сам обработчик вызывает добавление нового элемента. Например, для элементов создаваемых в коллбэках аякса пример с вызовом функции внутри себя не подходит по смыслу.

В итоге все сводится к unbind+bind...

Answer (score 2):

думаю, Вам надо копать в сторону

```
.on()
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод [delegate()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) - это практически синоним метода [live()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9). И как правильно заметил [[@oneboy](/users/5033/oneboy)](/users/5033/oneboy), с появлением метода [on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On), нужда в них пропала.