# jQuery инициализация radio после добавления

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть таблица с полями. Каждая строка - настройка для коммуникации с отделом. По клику добавляется еще одна строка. Если происходит добавление, то radio не работает. В посте [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-jquery-delegation-rebinding) сказано, что надо проводить rebinding. Как можно сделать для radio?

```
<tbody id="department-list">
<tr id="empty-row" hidden>
    <td class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control spinner" type="text"></td>
    <td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control spinner" type="text"></td>
    <td class="col-md-3 cell-center-align">
        <div class="radio-list form-inline margin-top-6px">
            <input type="radio" name="radios2" value="option1">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-3 cell-center-align">
        <div class="radio-list form-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radios2" value="option2" checked>      
            <select class="form-control input-small"></select></div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><a><i class="fa fa-trash font-dark"></i></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Получаю список из таких строк. name в радио заменяю на уникальные чтобы работало.

Добавление провожу посредством

```
$('#add-button').click(function() {
        var template = $('#empty-row').clone();
        template.removeAttr('hidden');
        template.find('input').attr('name', 'radioName' + radioId);
        radioId++;
        $('#department-list').append(template);
        initRemoveDepartment();
    })
```

Comment: Что есть "radio не работает"?

Comment: Ну то и есть, два переключения при клике на неактивное ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KYRAN - Дело не в клике на `"#add-button"`, а, скорее всего, в клике на `<input type="radio" ... />`.

@flybox - Используйте `$("body").on` для назначения события click для `<input type="radio" ... />`.

Comment: Разобрался, не думал что дело в плагине uniform. Но да, дело было в input type='radio' и его uniform таким образом искажал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `.on();`

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-button', function() {
    var template = $('#empty-row').clone();
    template.removeAttr('hidden');
    template.find('input').attr('name', 'radioName' + radioId);
    radioId++;
    $('#department-list').append(template);
    initRemoveDepartment();
});
```