# JQuery перестает видеть событие для определенного объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Допустим в коде с помощью JQuery есть событие нажатия на элемент id='button':

```
$(function (){$('#button').click(function() {
    alert('на меня нажали');
    }); 
});
```

Код прекрасно работает и все счастливы, но если элемент #button был удален и снова создан с помощью .innerHTML или к примеру его id был сменен на другой, а потом заменен обратно на #button, то выше написанная функция перестает работать. Будто бы JQuery считает, что #button больше нет. 
Вопрос: что это за явление и как его можно избежать? Если нельзя, то как можно реанимировать работу функции без обновления страницы?

**добавлено**: вопрос пересекается с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-jquery-delegation-rebinding) вопросом, но у меня вопрос о том, как заставить фнкцию работать после изменений или найти альтернативу, а там стоит вопрос об принципе работы "делегирования (delegation) и пересвязывания (rebinding)". Тем не менее может помочь в решение этого вопроса.

Comment: почитайте про [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с динамически добавленными элементами в jQuery (delegation, rebinding)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-jquery-delegation-rebinding)

Comment: @Grundy совсем не дубликат. Там вопрос "как оно работает", а тут "как это сделать".

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а разве зная как оно работает будет проблемой понять как это сделать? :-)

Comment: @Grundy в ответе на тот вопрос нет даже ни одного примера кода! Потому что тот, кто спрашивал - был, что называется, "в теме". Тот, кто спрашивает "как это сделать" - не поймет из объяснений "как это работает" вообще ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующий вариант

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
     alert('на меня нажали');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Применил.

Comment: @Владислав Климов, незачто

Comment: Ожидание ready тут было лишнее.

Comment: @ВладиславКлимов обратите внимание на исправление

Answer (score 2):

Описанная вами функция jQuery выполнится единоразово, сразу после загрузки страницы. Если после этого удалить со страницы, элемент который был подписан на событие, а потом снова его создать. То для вновь созданного элемента, подписки на нужное вам событие еще не существует. Ее нужно выполнить снова.

Во время вставки в документ элемента button, после очередного его удаления, одновременно с этими действиями выполните подписку на событие которое вам необходимо. Другими словами, в коде JS, где описывается вставка эдемента button, вставьте функцию, которая снова выполнит подписку данного элемента на нужное вас событие.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Данное решение с повторным вызовом функции вслед за изменениями элемента помогло. Остановился бы на этом, если бы не упоминание функции .on().

Comment: Я объяснил, почему оно не работает =) Вариант, предложенный с обработкой события клика по кнопке в элементе верхнего уровня (body) тоже правильный. При его использовании не имеет значение, какую бы вы использованли функцию для обработки события .on() или .click(), результат был бы одинаков.